# Setting id value for a ListBoxItem in Windows Mobile 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I'm trying to create a single select listbox from Linq, however, I'm running into problems setting the id value of each listbox item with the corresponding id as saved in a local database. I have the following code:

```
public void display_Tips()
    {
       //commented out to try MrMDavidson's approach.
       // listBoxTipHistory.Items.Clear();
       // IList<Tips> tips = this.get_Tips();
       // foreach (Tips tip in tips)
       // {
       //     ListBoxItem li1 = new ListBoxItem();
       //     li1.Content = tip.date.Day + "-" + tip.date.Month + "-" + 
       //                       tip.date.Year + "-" + tip.date.Hour + ":" +
       //                       tip.date.Minute + " - " + tip.resturant + " - $" +
       //                       tip.tip_amount + " - $" + tip.billTotal;
       //     listBoxTipHistory.Items.Add(li1);
       // }
        if (listBoxTipHistory.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            listBoxTipHistory.Items.Clear();
        }
        listBoxTipHistory.ItemsSource = get_Tips();
}

public IList<Tips> get_Tips()
    {
        IList<Tips> tips = null;
        using (TipContext context = new TipContext(conString))
        {
            IQueryable<Tips> query =
                (from c in context.TipTable
                 orderby c.date descending
                 select c);
            tips = query.ToList();
        }
        return tips;
    }
```

Table for local database:

```
[Table]
public class Tips
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int tip_ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public float tip_amount
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column]
    public string resturant
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
  }
```

Xaml code:

```
  <ListBox SelectionChanged="showTipDetails" x:Name="listBoxTipHistory" Margin="6,3,0,0">
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding resturant}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding tip_amount}" />
                      </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox >
```

I'm now trying to recode to work with MrMDavidson's suggestion, however, with this current code it results in the list showing "AppName.Tips" rather than the actual column data. I've tried googling walkthroughs and tutorials on this, however, I've been unable to come up with a solution.

Moreover, is there a special way to handle dates and time?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1468638.aspx/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to do this from a WinForms / CF.Net style approach. Whilst you can probably do this I'd recommend against it as you're really not getting the value of Silverlight. Let's presume that your `Tips` class looks something like;

```
public class Tip {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Restaurant { get; set; }
}
```

You can then bind a list of these to a `ListBox`;

```
listBoxTipHistory.ItemsSource = get_Tips()
```

Your `XAML` is used to describe how these items are displayed;

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxTipHistory">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Restaurant}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The `SelectedItem` on the `ListBox` will be the currently selected `Tip` (as an `object`), not the actual `ListBoxItem` that's selected. So to get the ID of the selected `Tip`;

```
Tip selectedTip = listBoxTipHistory.SelectedItem as Tip;
if (selectedTip != null) {
  Console.WriteLine("The selected Tip is {0}", selectedTip.Id);
}
```

A further suggestion would be for you to look into the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface which will allow changes to your model to automatically get updated in the UI

Comment: I've tried this approach, however my list results in "AppName.Tips" for each item listed. One of the items is labelled "resturant" and so I have created "<TextBlock Text="{Binding resturant}" />", nonetheless it doesn't display the intended result. Any suggestions? Furthermore, how would one show multiple items such as "resturant, title, id" within one textblock?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include multiple properties being bound. Can you clarify what you mean by "Labelled restaurant" ?

Comment: I've updated my question to better reflect your suggestion and the part that I'm stuck on.

Comment: Doh! I think I see the problem - I forgot the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` tag in the `XAML`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it. Now it looks like I will have to figure out multibinding for WP7 since this version of silverlight doesn't actually support it. :(

Comment: Correct - multibinding isn't supported on WP7's Silverlight. Depending on what you're doing the `StackPanel` approach (as shown) or `IValueConverter`s can do a reasonable facsimile (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=VS.95).aspx )

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MrMDavidson that you are approaching this from an old-school perspective, and I also agree that using a ViewModel / Binding approach would be nicer, but I'll give an answer that won't require you to rewrite what you've done so far.

Set the `DataContext` for the `ListItem` to the tip object:

```
foreach (Tips tip in tips)
{
    ListBoxItem li1 = new ListBoxItem();
    li1.Content = tip.date.Day + "-" // etc    
    li1.DataContext = tip;

    listBoxTipHistory.Items.Add(li1);
}
```

Think of the `DataContext` as a container behind the control (the `ListItem`) which contains an object. Ideally you'd have the `ListItem` retrieve data from its DataContext and populate its content, but that's for another day. For now just conceive of it as a container that you can use to store data relating to that control.

Now when you select an item or the user presses submit, you can retrieve the item easily:

```
foreach (var item in listBoxTipHistory.SelectedItems)
{
    var tip = (Tip)item.DataContext;
    var tipId = tip.tip_ID; // or whatever you need to do
}
```